# How do i let some text in a text box replace for example "-" with space in VB?

Tags: vb.net

How do i replace some text in a text box with another text? I use visual basic.
I tried something like

```
If Richtextbox1.Text Contains "-" Then
```

Dont laugh if it was completly wrong.

Comment: ...and what happened when you tried that?  Whats the rest of the code to do the replace?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.Replace instead of trying to do the replacement yourself. Here is an MSDN page with a link to the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

It would look something like this in your code:

```
Richtextbox1.Text = Richtextbox1.Text.Replace(profaneWord, "[redacted]")
```

Comment: Im kinda dumb, but how do i replace "-" with a space?